# Woocommerce order, update phone number metadata, remove special characters

Tags: php, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce

After a customer has placed an order, I want to update the order meta data. I would like to remove the "/" from the phone number meta data.
For example: 23/3245/235 -> 233245235
How should I do it?

I've tried this, which works, but it doesn't update the phone number, it creates a new custom field
`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'update_order_meta_phone' );
function update_order_meta_phone( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);   
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        // Replace before saving translating )
        $billing_phone = str_replace( array('/'), array(''), $_POST['billing_phone'] );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $billing_phone ) );
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Resources state this for **update_post_meta**:

[If the meta field for the post does not exist, it will be added and its ID returned.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

I assume in your case, this code block causes it:

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $billing_phone ) )
```

You can try this code block (or inspect your database table to get right column that refers to the "phone number"):

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_phone', $phone )
```

Plus:

1. You can also use woocommerce_thankyou by following https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-update-checkout-field-value-after-order/
2. You can use the phone number value that is stored in Order object ($order), no need to check & get $_POST['billing_phone'].